# Output returning Null

Tags: java

My class built to output the Month and month number builds and runs fine, but somewhere in my class my monthString is just being assigned null. I cannot see where I have ran into this mistake, and I apologize for my bad code. TY! ~~~

```
public class MonthClass
{

private int monthNum;
private String monthString;



    public MonthClass(int num)
{
        monthNum = num;
        monthString = monthName(num);
}

    public void setmonthNum(int num)
{
        monthNum = num;
        monthString = monthName(num);
}   


public String getmonthName(int num)
{




 switch (num)
  {
 case 1: monthString = "January";
    break;
 case 2: monthString = "Febuary";
    break;
 case 3: monthString = "March";
    break;
 case 4: monthString = "April";
    break;
 case 5: monthString = "May";
    break;
 case 6: monthString = "June";
    break;
 case 7: monthString = "July";
    break;
 case 8: monthString= "Augest";
    break;
 case 9: monthString = "September";
    break;
 case 10: monthString = "October";
    break;
 case 11: monthString = "November";
    break;
 case 12: monthString = "December";
    break;
 default: monthString = "This is not a month, re-enter a number";
    break;

  }
  return monthString;
 }






    public String monthName(int num)
{
        return monthString;
}

public String toString()
{
return "The month number is " + monthNum + " and the month name is " + monthString;
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not use words of profanity. This site is not age restricted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code at no place modifies `monthString`, and its value always remains `null` (default value for reference types).

Instead of `monthName` you should be calling `getmonthName` (the conversion from month number to string is happening there):

```
monthString = getmonthName(num);
```

Method `monthName` is only a *getter* - it doesn't modify the `monthString`. Also as this method doesn't make use of any argument, you can possibly get rid of that too:

```
public String monthName() {
    return monthString;
}
```

Also, in the `default` case in the `switch` statement, the assignment of non-month string is going to happen silently. You might want to print something on the console as well.